# Customize Vuforia's Augmented reality sample code for user-Defined Target

Tags: ios, augmented-reality, vuforia

I have gone through Vuforia's sample code for **user Defined Target**. I really dont find any clues on modifying the sample code to render some text instead of rendering the 3D model(the teapot). Can anyone help me understand how to change the sample code to render a text?

Comment: do you need to render the text as a 3D object model?

Comment: No i Just wanted a UILabel.text instead of displaying a 3D model.

Answer (score 0):

You should start by reading [this vuforia "knowledge database" article](https://developer.vuforia.com/resources/dev-guide/textured-plane-target), which explains how to replace the teapot with a textured plane.

Once you've done that, the simplest way to display text will be to generate a texture containing this text, and display it on the plane. [This other article](https://developer.vuforia.com/resources/dev-guide/adding-textures) explains how to use other textures than the 2 that are provided with the sample app.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I just needed a UILabel.text instead of the 3D object. Anyways i have found if I modify code in the method 'renderFrameQCAR', I was able to display a UILabel instead of the 3d teapot. But can you tell me if this is the right way of implementing it or do u suggest something else?